# MySQL select * from last 5 days from a datetime field

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table which looks like this

```
id  datetime  tick_info(string)
0  16-10-2013 3:33:01  "33300"
1  17-10-2013 5:04:01  "003023"
2  17-10-2013 6:12:04  "3244"
3  19-10-2013 5:32:12  "3333332"
4  20-10-2013 8:14:44  "33321"
5  20-10-2013 9:12:11  "5821"
6  22-10-2013 10:32:11 "33111"
```

And so the data can span for 20 days and I want to select all rows with the last 5 days. Note that the last 5 days mean : the 5 latest distinct date in the table.

Ex : 17-19-20-22-23 in the case where there is no tick_info for the 21 and the 18.

The number of tick_info is variable so there might be 100 tick_info for the 20 and 5 for the 23.

I'm using mysql.

*Update* Should have mentioned I'm using mysql 5.5.32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this::

```
Select 
* 
from 
'myTable' 
where 'datetime' >=
      (
           select  
          `datetime` 
          from myTable 
          group by DATE(`datetime`) 
          order by `datetime` desc 4,1
        )
```

Comment: and what about 5 days backwards restriction?

Comment: @Antoniossss: that is exact my logic, to get the 5th day and get the records from that day

Comment: how come? I just dont get it

Comment: @Antoniossss: My inner query returns the 5th oldest day, and the outer query returns all the rows having tick_info >the 5th updated day

Comment: Oh, but it returns first 5 unique backward dates. If there will be gap between days, you will get records from more that 5 days isn't it?

Comment: yes this is what OP want, if he wanted the 5th day from the current date, your query will work perfectly fine

Comment: Ahh, ok, I misundersood question than. +1

Comment: There is a problem with your query. But I was successful with
`select * from 'my_table' where 'datetime' > (select 'datetime' from 'my_table' group by DATE('datetime') order by 'datetime' desc limit 4,1);` note the limit 4,1  ; why does that give us the 5 last days (where as 5,1 would give the 6 last days?

Comment: @Lazik: just change the `limit 5,1` to `limit 4,1`

Comment: @Lazik
limit has two parameters if you use 
`LIMIT n` it will return you n rows
`LIMIT m,n` returns you n rows from mth row

Comment: Gotcha, I was confused with the datetime > operator. When you accept my edit and I'll accept your answer

Comment: Seems like my edit must go through peer-review... You should be able to see it

Comment: You need to change the first portion of the sql:
`Select * from 'datetime' where tick_info >` Should be `Select * from 'myTable' where 'datetime' >=`

Comment: @Lazik: Thanks for pointing out, well it was done in a hurry, hope you got the logic

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE tick_info>=DATE_SUB(tick_info, INTERVAL 5 DAY) group by tick_info order by tick_info DESC`

Comment: will not give the result OP wants

Answer (score 0):

Please check my query it is cent percent working

I tested it

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE tick_info>=DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) group by tick_info order by tick_info DESC
```